# Why does my python script delete itself?

Tags: python, biopython

I am working on a script that converts multiple fastq files into fasta and qual. Always when I run it, the script has zero bytes afterwards.

```
import sys
import re
import os
import fileinput
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

Directory = "/users/etc"
def process(Directory):
    filelist = os.listdir(Directory)
    for f in filelist:
        SeqIO.convert(f, "fastq", f.replace(".fastq",".qual"), "qual", alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)

my_directory = "/users/etc"
process(my_directory)
```

I struggle with doing both fastq to fasta AND qual conversion at the same time - just copying the SeqIO.convert line and exchanging the file formats does not do the trick...
Also, I would love to have a number printed of how many files have been converted.

Cheers

Comment: Adjust file permissions to make the script read-only. See which operation fails when you run it -- then you'll know what's overwriting it.

Comment: Also, this can't be your actual code -- it has an indentation error and won't run.

Comment: sorry, changed!

Comment: As an aside -- see [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for conventions around Python code style and naming -- names starting with a capital letter are appropriate for classes, but *not* for module-scoped variables or parameters.

Comment: One rather important question, by the way -- what directory is your script saved in, and what is its filename?

Comment: the script is in an directory on the desktop together with the fastq files, filename is fasta.py

Comment: (And how exactly are you invoking that Python script -- if you're running it from another script, do you still get a bug if you start it by hand?)

Comment: Yeah. So, step one: Keep your code in a different place from where you keep your data.

Comment: i always cd in the directory, then python fasta.py

Comment: btw, I didn't answer tracking the counter because we have rules here about a question's breadth and scope -- basically, "one question to a question". That said -- what part of it do you not know how to do? I mean, really the only parts are initialization (`i=0`), increment (`i += 1`), and printing (`print("Processed %d files" % i)`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this loop:

```
filelist = os.listdir(Directory)
for f in filelist:
    SeqIO.convert(f, "fastq", f.replace(".fastq",".qual"), "qual", alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
```

...you're looping over **every file** in your directory.

Not every file except your Python script, or every file that ends in `.fastq`, but **every file**.

Because `'yourscript.py'.replace('.fastq', '.qual')` is still `'yourscript.py'`, this then overwrites the Python script by trying to use it as output as well as input.

---

So, there are a few notes here:

- Keep data and code separate. Ideally, in completely different directories. A `$HOME/bin` directory is an appropriate place to keep your own code -- if you add that directory to your `PATH`, then you can run executable commands in it from anywhere.
- In your loop, filter out filenames that don't end in `.fastq`. That may look like:

  ```
  for f in filelist:
      if not f.endswith('.fastq'):
          continue
      SeqIO.convert(f, 'fastq', f[:-len('.fastq')]+'.qual', 'qual', alphabet=IUPAC.ambiguous_dna)
  ```
- Since after adding this check we know that `.fastq` exists at the *end* of a filename, we can thus be a little more efficient about replacing it -- instead of searching through the whole name for the string, we can just prune that many characters off the end, and then tack the new extension on instead. This is both a bit faster and means we don't modify any part of a filename except the extension.

Comment: Wohoo.. made my day!